# How can I get the value of the selected index of listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, sql-server-express, population

```
string KaloriSorgusu = "use FoodDB select drink_kal from Drinks";
SqlConnection baglanti2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + IPFORM.ip.ToString() + "\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=UserDB;User Id=Levent; Password=21012101;Trusted_Connection=False;Integrated Security=False");
 using (baglanti2)
 {
     using (SqlCommand KaloriKomutu = new SqlCommand(KaloriSorgusu, baglanti2))
     {
         baglanti2.Open();
         using (SqlDataReader KALORİokuyucu = KaloriKomutu.ExecuteReader())
         {
              while (KALORİokuyucu.Read())
              {
                  lb_Kalori.Items.Add(KALORİokuyucu.GetValue(0).ToString());
                  total = lb_Kalori.Items.Count;
              }
         }
     }
}
```

This code populates the listbox and when I try to get values from selected index I can't seem to find a way to get the value of an index.

Comment: it's not clear what you trying to do you have `KALORİokuyucu` which will hold values from a `SqlDataReader` Object` now if you want to get the value to assign to the `lblKalori` you should do `lb_Kalori.Items.Add((string)KALORİokuyucu["FieldNameYouWant"]);` Also are you sure only `1 Item` will be returned when assigning to the label? otherwise you will override the previous assignment if more than one records is returned. `meaning you will need to change the .ExcuteReader() call to ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: Why not put the instantiation of `baglanti2` into the `using` block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this little snippet will help you.

```
// Get the currently selected item in the ListBox. 
   string curItem = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

 // Find the string in ListBox2. 
  int index = listBox2.FindString(curItem);
 // If the item was not found in ListBox 2 display a message box, otherwise select it in        ListBox2. 
 if(index == -1)
    MessageBox.Show("Item is not available in ListBox2");
 else
   listBox2.SetSelected(index,true);`
```